# 'curl' command works intermittently

Tags: centos, netstat, kubernetes

I am trying to install and configure a high availability RKE2 cluster (Rancher Kubernetes Engine 2). My architecture consists of 4 VMs: one with DNS and LoadBalancer configured, another with the server node up and running, and a 2 VMs intended as the node to join.

The logs from the agent node are stating:

```
    Jul 27 13:10:22 ha-rancher-2 rke2[31465]: time="2023-07-27T13:10:22Z" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: failed to get CA certs: https://rancher.inwi.priv:9345/cacerts: 503 Service Unavailable"
Jul 27 13:10:22 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: rke2-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 27 13:10:22 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Rancher Kubernetes Engine v2 (server).
Jul 27 13:10:22 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: Unit rke2-server.service entered failed state.
Jul 27 13:10:22 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: rke2-server.service failed.
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: rke2-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: Stopped Rancher Kubernetes Engine v2 (server).
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: Starting Rancher Kubernetes Engine v2 (server)...
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 sh[31479]: + /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 sh[31479]: Failed to get unit file state for nm-cloud-setup.service: No such file or directory
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 rke2[31485]: time="2023-07-27T13:10:28Z" level=warning msg="not running in CIS mode"
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 rke2[31485]: time="2023-07-27T13:10:28Z" level=info msg="Starting rke2 v1.24.15+rke2r1 (8cf3a75d5ccd6e2aa0a99cdf869426f1decd970d)"
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 rke2[31485]: time="2023-07-27T13:10:28Z" level=info msg="Managed etcd cluster not yet initialized"
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 rke2[31485]: time="2023-07-27T13:10:28Z" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: failed to validate server configuration: CA cert validation failed: https://rancher.inwi.priv:9345/cacerts: 503 Service Unavailable"
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: rke2-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Rancher Kubernetes Engine v2 (server).
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: Unit rke2-server.service entered failed state.
Jul 27 13:10:28 ha-rancher-2 systemd[1]: rke2-server.service failed.
```

I attempted to investigate the problem, but what I find strange is that the 'curl' command works intermittently, which is confusing.

```
    [root@HA-Rancher-2 ~]# curl -vks https://rancher.inwi.priv:9345/cacerts                                                                                * About to connect() to rancher.inwi.priv port 9345 (#0)
*   Trying 172.20.10.210...
* Connected to rancher.inwi.priv (172.20.10.210) port 9345 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=rke2,O=rke2
*       start date: Jul 25 19:12:23 2023 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 25 22:54:08 2024 GMT
*       common name: rke2
*       issuer: CN=rke2-server-ca@1690312343
> GET /cacerts HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: rancher.inwi.priv:9345
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2023 14:34:58 GMT
< Content-Length: 570
<
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBeTCCAR+gAwIBAgIBADAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAkMSIwIAYDVQQDDBlya2UyLXNl
cnZlci1jYUAxNjkwMzEyMzQzMB4XDTIzMDcyNTE5MTIyM1oXDTMzMDcyMjE5MTIy
M1owJDEiMCAGA1UEAwwZcmtlMi1zZXJ2ZXItY2FAMTY5MDMxMjM0MzBZMBMGByqG
SM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABJdeIAgxOwLhgv7IH4hloybTf...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
* Connection #0 to host rancher.inwi.priv left intact
[root@HA-Rancher-2 ~]# curl -vks https://rancher.inwi.priv:9345/cacerts
* About to connect() to rancher.inwi.priv port 9345 (#0)
*   Trying 172.20.10.210...
* Connected to rancher.inwi.priv (172.20.10.210) port 9345 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=rke2,O=rke2
*       start date: Jul 25 19:12:23 2023 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 25 22:54:20 2024 GMT
*       common name: rke2
*       issuer: CN=rke2-server-ca@1690312343
> GET /cacerts HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: rancher.inwi.priv:9345
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2023 14:35:00 GMT
< Content-Length: 9
<
starting
* Connection #0 to host rancher.inwi.priv left intact**strong text**
```

With the "netstat" command form the LB vm, I can observe that the connection state remains in "TIME_WAIT" for over 2 minutes instead of transitioning to "ESTABLISHED" for the port I am working with, which is port 9345.

```
  Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 rancher:48916           172.20.10.11:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:48898           172.20.10.11:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:48958           172.20.10.11:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:56558           172.20.10.14:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:48988           172.20.10.11:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:ssh             172.20.10.200:44748     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 rancher:48978           172.20.10.11:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:56568           172.20.10.14:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:9345            172.20.10.13:40856      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:9345            172.20.10.13:40892      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:56538           172.20.10.14:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:48924           172.20.10.11:9345       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 rancher:56526           172.20.10.14:9345       TIME_WAIT
udp        0      0 rancher:34185           8.8.8.8:domain          ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 rancher:41489           8.8.4.4:domain          ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 rancher:47731           8.8.8.8:domain          ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 rancher:40760           8.8.8.8:domain          ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: done, do you have any clues or suggestions for my issue ??

Comment: I don't see a failure in `curl`.  The third example shows curl making a connection to the load balancer, issuing a `GET /cacerts` and receiving a 502 response from the web service in the load balancer (or behind it).  That's a successful network connection, request, and answer.  The reason the response is 502 instead of 200 will be found in the logs of the http service that responded.

Comment: the logs in /var/log/niginx are showing : ```2023/07/27 03:07:40 [error] 1873#1873: *1409 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.10.13, server: 0.0.0.0:9345, upstream: "172.20.10.13:9345", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0 ```

Comment: In the nginx logs "upstream" means the back-end service that nginx is balancing for.  In this case, something wasn't accepting connections on port 9345.  I'm guessing it's one of the RKE pods.  The trouble connecting to the back-end resource caused nginx to return a 502 to your curl client.  Does your RKE have monitoring of whether or not pods are accepting connections?